# Specflow nunit test report is blank

Tags: c#, xamarin, nunit, specflow

I'm writing a Xamarin UI Test app via specflow.

Im using Specflow nunit reporting to try and generate a test report

I run the unit tests with

"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\bin\nunit-console.exe" path_to_project_dll

I then run the specflow report within the directory of the testresults.xml file

"path\specflow.exe" nunitexecutionreport path_to_csproj /out:path_to_html_output

The output is a test report that recognises the features but doesnt give any information about the tests.

[image: TwitterTestCapture]

Appreciate any ideas. Thanks

Comment: Are you using NUnit3? There was a change in the xml- Layout and SpecFlow is not yet fully changed to it.

Comment: I was yes, I downgraded to 2.6.4 and it worked. Thank you

Comment: I seem having the same issue. Is there a workaround?