# How to generate specflow nunit testresult.xml

Tags: c#, nunit, bdd, specflow

I have written BDD for webservices, I have to generate reports for that. So please let me know the step by step creation of `testresult.xml` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments in 
[Specflow nunit test report is blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073068/specflow-nunit-test-report-is-blank?rq=1)

i downgraded to nunit framework 2.6.4 ,it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation: http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Reporting/

Comment: Yes,I have a look at this document.But I am getting below error :
C:\Users\nb\Downloads\NUnit-3.2.1\bin>nunit3-console.exe /labels
ult.txt /out=TestResult.xml  D:\LegacyUrlRedirectionPOC_NEW\LegacyUr
POC\TestLegacyUrlRedirectionPOC\TestLegacyUrlRedirectionPOC\bin\Debu
UrlRedirectionPOC.dll
NUnit Console Runner 3.2.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Charlie Poole

The value '/out=TestResult.txt' is not valid for option '--labels'.

Comment: Also if i generate .xml without using label tag, using command :
nunit3-console.exe /out=TestResult.xml  D:\LegacyUrlRedirectionPOC_NEW\LegacyUrlRedirectionPOC\TestLegacyUrlRedirectionPOC\TestLegacyUrlRedirectionPOC\bin\Debug\TestLegacyUrlRedirectionPOC.dll   then i am able to generate html report using this .xml but its not having detailed scenario execution traces.So please let me know how to generate html reports with all the details...Regards

Answer (score 0):

With SpecFlow dotnet5 you can generate a trx results file executing:

```
dotnet test --logger "trx;LogFileName=results.trx"
```

After that, Instal this tool globally https://github.com/gfoidl/trx2junit

```
dotnet tool install --global trx2junit --version 2.0.0
```

Convert that trx file into junit file

```
trx2junit results.trx

trx2junit (c) gfoidl -- v2.0.0
https://github.com/gfoidl/trx2junit

Converting 1 trx file(s) to JUnit-xml...
Converting 'results.trx' to 'results.xml'
done in 0.0738152 seconds. bye.
```

The `results.xml` is generated with the junit format expected.